# Implementing custom Utility instead of `window.location.assign`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, controller, routes

I am using AngularJS, and in the controller, I have a function, like this.

```
  ctrl.onClick = (id) => {
    window.location.assign(`#/services/${id}`);
  }
```

I want to use one of our custom locationUtils. Here is the code for that:

```
export const redirectTo = (route) => {
  const { location } = window;
  location.href = `${location.origin}${route}`;
};
```

I am importing it to the controller and the path is correct. But with what I have written the redirect doesn't work.

Here is my implementation:

```
  ctrl.onBrokerClick = (id) => {
    redirectTo(`#/services/${id}`);
  }
```

What the heck am I doing wrong here? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just to answer my own question here. When the `redirectTo()` was getting called, it provided the prefix `homepage`. In my function, instead of this:

```
ctrl.onBrokerClick = (id) => {
    redirectTo(`#/services/${id}`);
  }
```

I did this in order to supplement that missing prefix:

```
ctrl.onBrokerClick = (id) => {
    redirectTo(`/homepage/#/services/${id}`);
  }
```

It is by far the less elegant solution, but for now it works. I will have to look to what @front_end_dev said.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `history.pushState(null,null,'new_url_address')` to load new url.

Follow this documentation for history api - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Yeah, I can solve it with a lot more solutions, with just JS. I need to do it with our Util. So, in the future, we will have only a couple points of failure, and knkow where to look. Thanks though!!

Comment: You can change your redirectTo implementation. Instead of fetching `location` and working on that you can now fetch `history` object from window and work the way I provide solution.

Comment: Wouldn't that work, only in case I have the `history` object. Let's say it's a new session. In your implementation, I should have an if statement, and 2 functions, a `redirectTo()` and a `historyRedirect()`. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: `history` object is of window property so it's always present and you are pushing state into it not popping out from it. Regarding if state there is no need for maintain it and you can easily use `historyRedirect` for all the use cases you have.